# Scalajs WebGL "Hello World!"

Tags: scala, scala.js

OK its not a literal "Hello World!" programme, but the equivalent: it outputs a couple of triangles to the canvas using a WebGL rendering context.

The program works as it should, but is there any way to get rid of those nasty dynamic casts and the inelegant scalajs Arrays initialisations in the second half of the programme. Obviously I can create my own utility functions / classes (I'm using my own utilities for generating the shader source code), but I would prefer to use the scalajs standard methods where possible.

```
package pClient
import org.scalajs._
import dom._
import pUtil._

object ClientApp extends scalajs.js.JSApp
  {
    def main(): Unit =  
    {
      var can: html.Canvas =    document.createElement("canvas").asInstanceOf[html.Canvas]
      document.body.appendChild(can)
      can.width = window.innerWidth
      can.height = window.innerHeight - 60

      import raw.WebGLRenderingContext._
      var gl: raw.WebGLRenderingContext = can.getContext("webgl").asInstanceOf[raw.WebGLRenderingContext]     
      gl.clearColor(0.4, 0.0, 0.5, 0.8)
      gl.clear(COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)     

      var vShader = gl.createShader(VERTEX_SHADER)     
      var vertText = "attribute vec2 position;" -+ VMain(Seq("gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);")).out(0)     
      gl.shaderSource(vShader, vertText)     
      gl.compileShader(vShader)     

      var fShader = gl.createShader(FRAGMENT_SHADER)
      var fragText = "precision highp float;" -+ "uniform vec4 color;" -+ VMain(Seq("gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);")).out(0)
      gl.shaderSource(fShader, fragText)
      gl.compileShader(fShader)

      var program = gl.createProgram()
      gl.attachShader(program, vShader)
      gl.attachShader(program, fShader)
      gl.linkProgram(program)     

      var tempVertices: scalajs.js.Array[Float] = scalajs.js.Array[Float]()
      tempVertices.push(-0.3f,-0.3f,   0.3f,-0.3f,  0.0f,0.3f,  0.2f,0.2f,   0.6f, 0.6f,   0.4f, -0.4f)     
      import scalajs.js.typedarray.Float32Array
      var vertices: Float32Array = new Float32Array(tempVertices)

      var buffer = gl.createBuffer()
      gl.bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
      gl.bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, STATIC_DRAW)

      gl.useProgram(program)
      var progDyn = program.asInstanceOf[scalajs.js.Dynamic]
      progDyn.color = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "color")
      var temp2 = scalajs.js.Array[Double]()
      temp2.push(0f, 1f, 0.5f, 1.0f)
      gl.uniform4fv(progDyn.color.asInstanceOf[raw.WebGLUniformLocation], temp2)

      progDyn.position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position")
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(progDyn.position.asInstanceOf[Int])
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(progDyn.position.asInstanceOf[Int], 2, FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
      gl.drawArrays(TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 2)     
    } 
}
```

I'm working the programme in Eclipse. It has the following jars on the path:

```
scalajs-cli-assembly_2.11-0.6.5.jar
scalajs-compiler_2.11.7-0.6.5.jar
scalajs-dom_sjs0.6_2.11-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
scalajs-library_2.11-0.6.5.jar
```

and I'm continuous building with sbt. build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
name := "ScalaClient"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.8.0"
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
scalacOptions := Seq("-feature", "-language:implicitConversions", "-deprecation", "-target:jvm-1.8")
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("/sdat/scalaPackages/pUtil")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can significantly improve the array initializations like this:

```
import scala.scalajs.js // common import in Scala.js
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray._

val vertices = new Float32Array(js.Array(
    -0.3f,-0.3f,  0.3f,-0.3f,  0.0f,0.3f,  0.2f,0.2f,
    0.6f,0.6f,  0.4f,-0.4f))
```

As for casts to `js.Dynamic`, that is mostly a consequence of the types for WebGL not being as good as they could be. `WebGLProgram` is empty at this point. Feel free to contribute improvements to those typings!

Comment: I think part of my problem was that I was getting confused by the difference between scala.scalajs and org.scalajs. Thanks, now I'll have to see if its straight forward mapping to js.Array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your example in ScalaFiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Rb13PUG/8

```
import fiddle.Fiddle, Fiddle.println
import scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray._
import org.scalajs.dom
import dom.raw.WebGLRenderingContext._

object ScalaFiddle extends js.JSApp{
  def main(): Unit = {
    var can: dom.html.Canvas = dom.document.createElement("canvas").asInstanceOf[dom.html.Canvas]
    dom.document.body.appendChild(can)
    can.width = Fiddle.canvas.width
    can.height = Fiddle.canvas.height

    var gl: dom.raw.WebGLRenderingContext = can.getContext("webgl").asInstanceOf[dom.raw.WebGLRenderingContext]     
    gl.clearColor(0.4, 0.0, 0.5, 0.8)
    gl.clear(COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    var vShader = gl.createShader(VERTEX_SHADER)     
    var vertText = "attribute vec2 position; void main() {gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);}"
    gl.shaderSource(vShader, vertText)     
    gl.compileShader(vShader)     

    var fShader = gl.createShader(FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    var fragText = "precision highp float; uniform vec4 color; void main() {gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);}"
    gl.shaderSource(fShader, fragText)
    gl.compileShader(fShader)

    var program = gl.createProgram()
    gl.attachShader(program, vShader)
    gl.attachShader(program, fShader)
    gl.linkProgram(program)     

    val vertices = new Float32Array(js.Array(
    -0.3f,-0.3f,  0.3f,-0.3f,  0.0f,0.3f,  0.2f,0.2f,
    0.6f,0.6f,  0.4f,-0.4f))

    var buffer = gl.createBuffer()
    gl.bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
    gl.bufferData(ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, STATIC_DRAW)

    gl.useProgram(program)
    var progDyn = program.asInstanceOf[scalajs.js.Dynamic]
    progDyn.color = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "color")
    var temp2 = scalajs.js.Array[Double]()
    temp2.push(0f, 1f, 0.5f, 1.0f)
    gl.uniform4fv(progDyn.color.asInstanceOf[dom.raw.WebGLUniformLocation], temp2)

    progDyn.position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position")
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(progDyn.position.asInstanceOf[Int])
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(progDyn.position.asInstanceOf[Int], 2, FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
    gl.drawArrays(TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 2)     
  }
}
```